# Can't unserialize jQuery data with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I am trying to implement a modal AJAX form.  But when I press "Submit" I only receive empty body emails. I guess I have bugs in PHP code.

HTML:

```
<form class="form" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".form").submit(function() {
    var this1= $(this);
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    if (is_empty(this1)){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "feedback.php",
            data: form_data,
            success: function (res) {
                swal("Thank you", "very much", "success");
                $('.black_layout').fadeOut(200);
                $('.main_form_wrapper').fadeOut(200);
                this1.trigger('reset');
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

PHP in feedback.php file:

```
parse_str($_POST['form_data'], $formdata);

$name = $formdata['name'];
$phone=$formdata['phone'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Phone: $phone";
$recipient = "email@gmail.com";
$subject = "MAIL HEADER";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent) or die("Error");
```

EDIT:I am also not getting a "Thank you" message for some reason.

Comment: You're only sending the data if `is_empty(this1)`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Look at the posted data in the raw, you should be able to work out where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error during sending form data with ajax request. here is your code which is working fine :

JQuery :

```
$(".form").submit(function() { 
var this1= $(this);
var form_data = $(this).serialize();
alert(form_data);
//if (is_empty(this1)){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "feedback.php",
        data: {'form_data' : form_data },
        success: function (res) { alert(res);
            //swal("Thank you", "very much", "success");
            $('.black_layout').fadeOut(200);
            $('.main_form_wrapper').fadeOut(200);
            this1.trigger('reset');
        }
    });
//}
return false;
```

});